# Installing Brother driver/software causing kernel panic

Tags: macos, printing, kernel-panic, driver

I'm trying to install the Brother drivers for my Brother MFC-L5750DW on Mac OS X, but the installer app keeps crashing.

I've called with customer support, who confirmed I'm trying to install the right drivers.

I struggle to read stack traces. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

```
Process:               StartHereOSX [85613]
Path:                  /private/var/folders/*/StartHereOSX.app/Contents/MacOS/StartHereOSX
Identifier:            com.brother.utility.StartHereOSX
Version:               2.3.2 (84)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           StartHereOSX [85613]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-09-29 11:36:10.149 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13 (17A365)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y618b)

Time Awake Since Boot: 84000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       13000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Notes:                 Translocated Process

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSBundle initWithURL:]: nil URL argument'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff27c110fb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff4e4fdc76 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff27ca2bfd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff29c46395 -[NSBundle initWithURL:] + 87
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff29c4632b +[NSBundle bundleWithURL:] + 45
5   StartHereOSX                        0x0000000107ff0471 StartHereOSX + 25713
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff27b8df49 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 249
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff25178149 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1594
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff2527392e -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 679
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff254e7971 -[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 204
10  StartHereOSX                        0x0000000107feb939 StartHereOSX + 6457
11  StartHereOSX                        0x0000000107fed57b StartHereOSX + 13691
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff25178971 -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 364
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff251787a4 -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 288
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff25177d55 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 582
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff2516f31d loadNib + 435
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff2516e841 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 696
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff2516e486 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 204
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff2516e247 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 447
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff2516c2d2 NSApplicationMain + 504
20  StartHereOSX                        0x0000000107feb0ac StartHereOSX + 4268

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff4f23bfce __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff4f379150 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff4f19832a abort + 127
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff4d17df8f abort_message + 245
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff4d17e12b default_terminate_handler() + 265
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff4e4ffea3 _objc_terminate() + 97
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff4d1997c9 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff4d19926d __cxa_throw + 121
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff4e4fdda5 objc_exception_throw + 351
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff27ca2bfd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff29c46395 -[NSBundle initWithURL:] + 87
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff29c4632b +[NSBundle bundleWithURL:] + 45
12  com.brother.utility.StartHereOSX    0x0000000107ff0471 0x107fea000 + 25713
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff27b8df49 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 249
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff25178149 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1594
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2527392e -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 679
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff254e7971 -[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 204
17  com.brother.utility.StartHereOSX    0x0000000107feb939 0x107fea000 + 6457
18  com.brother.utility.StartHereOSX    0x0000000107fed57b 0x107fea000 + 13691
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff25178971 -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 364
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff251787a4 -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 288
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff25177d55 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 582
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2516f31d loadNib + 435
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2516e841 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 696
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2516e486 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 204
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2516e247 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 447
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2516c2d2 NSApplicationMain + 504
27  com.brother.utility.StartHereOSX    0x0000000107feb0ac 0x107fea000 + 4268

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff4f23c6da __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff4f37606a _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff4f375c4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff4f23c6da __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff4f37626f _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff4f375c4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff4f23c6da __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff4f37606a _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff4f375c4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff4f375c40 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0xffff9fbffffc9140 0 + 18446638245715153216

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff887bb340  rcx: 0x00007ffee7c13458  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffee7c13490  rsp: 0x00007ffee7c13458
   r8: 0x00007ffee7c13320   r9: 0x00007ffee7c134f0  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x0000000000000030  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x000000000000002d
  rip: 0x00007fff4f23bfce  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff88799148

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x107fea000 -        0x108003fff +com.brother.utility.StartHereOSX (2.3.2 - 84) <6410D11B-7A84-308D-91CE-BF6ADF1C41F4> /var/folders/*/StartHereOSX.app/Contents/MacOS/StartHereOSX
       0x1146cd000 -        0x11471798f  dyld (519.2.1) <002B0442-3D59-3159-BA10-1C0A77859C6A> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff2413b000 -     0x7fff2413bfff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <04FC5A30-0382-3FEB-BE8B-E14E9FF4EBD5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff4f0eb000 -     0x7fff4f108ff7  libdyld.dylib (519.2.1) <2597D818-42D2-3375-BD9D-451D5942A6BA> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff4f109000 -     0x7fff4f109ffb  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <6D84A96F-C65B-38EC-BDB5-21FD2C97E7B2> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff4f10a000 -     0x7fff4f116ff3  libkxld.dylib (4570.1.46) <AE8CE609-ECB8-3D2E-8823-C103A56064DF> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff4f117000 -     0x7fff4f117ff7  liblaunch.dylib (1205.1.10) <5AD77A68-BB4D-33AA-AA4F-DF51D0972FD9> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff4f118000 -     0x7fff4f11cffb  libmacho.dylib (900.0.1) <756F2553-07B6-3B42-ACEA-2F0F1A5E8D0F> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff4f11d000 -     0x7fff4f11fff3  libquarantine.dylib (86) <6AC8773F-3817-3D82-99C2-01BABB9C3CBB> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff4f120000 -     0x7fff4f121ff3  libremovefile.dylib (45) <912FA211-DD8C-3C92-8424-21B89F8B10FD> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff4f122000 -     0x7fff4f139fff  libsystem_asl.dylib (356.1.1) <94972913-9DF0-3C78-847C-43E58919E3DA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff4f13a000 -     0x7fff4f13afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (67) <F2493BB5-B1C6-3C4D-9F1F-1B402E0F1DB7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff4f13b000 -     0x7fff4f1c4fff  libsystem_c.dylib (1244.1.7) <2D4C21C0-9938-3552-8DC1-2C1CFAA10D38> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff4f1c5000 -     0x7fff4f1c8ffb  libsystem_configuration.dylib (963) <D7EFEAE6-22A0-348E-BBBE-44FFD41934FA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff4f1c9000 -     0x7fff4f1ccffb  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (51) <21A488D0-2D07-344E-8631-CC8B2A246F35> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff4f1cd000 -     0x7fff4f1cefff  libsystem_darwin.dylib (1244.1.7) <552C05CA-D151-3F93-B570-413340BDA9C7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
    0x7fff4f1cf000 -     0x7fff4f1d5ff7  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (878.1.1) <6E28973E-A258-36F6-ACFB-259ED5885C7A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff4f1d6000 -     0x7fff4f21fff7  libsystem_info.dylib (517) <483BE95B-62EB-3663-ACB3-9915A40C70F5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff4f220000 -     0x7fff4f245ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (4570.1.46) <71BA15CB-3056-3CBD-A5F5-EE61566EEA0C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff4f246000 -     0x7fff4f291fcb  libsystem_m.dylib (3146) <ABB1B85F-9FFE-31B8-AD4F-E39A30794A93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff4f292000 -     0x7fff4f2b1fff  libsystem_malloc.dylib (140.1.1) <9F0745FF-B92F-330D-8812-BB74001D1D33> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff4f2b2000 -     0x7fff4f355ff3  libsystem_network.dylib (1229.1.5) <A51EB0A4-9AA5-3F84-8E25-DD8EABE0F97E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff4f356000 -     0x7fff4f360ffb  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (767.1.4) <E842569D-00BA-3DE7-AD5A-9EF33422CF3E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff4f361000 -     0x7fff4f36aff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (172) <98EA3D62-7C86-30DE-8261-D020D2F1EFF3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff4f36b000 -     0x7fff4f372ff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (161) <9F5A67F7-BC65-300F-BD74-07E7732D6372> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff4f373000 -     0x7fff4f37eff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (301.1.6) <6D0B0110-2B44-3D3C-B672-BD08FE46378A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff4f37f000 -     0x7fff4f382ffb  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (765.1.8) <EC909728-0365-3710-B00B-0BCFCE03DC71> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff4f383000 -     0x7fff4f384ff3  libsystem_secinit.dylib (30) <F06ADB8F-9E94-34A7-B3C9-2C22FDD14BAD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff4f385000 -     0x7fff4f38cff7  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (820.1.4) <BF0566B2-9475-3B5C-8641-7910F313BA3C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff4f38d000 -     0x7fff4f3a0ff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (829.1.2) <10955EBB-1AC8-3085-9A2D-F3088CA2DF71> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff4f3a2000 -     0x7fff4f3a7ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <6D4FCD49-D2A9-3233-95C7-A7635CE265F2> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff4f3a8000 -     0x7fff4f3d3ff7  libxpc.dylib (1205.1.10) <E7C5DB12-6D0E-3D1E-A743-F750DF112F5F> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 78562
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=317.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=317.2M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=109.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=109.1M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
CoreServices                       168K        2 
CoreUI image file                  180K        4 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            98.3M       32 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       13 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        6 
Stack                             10.0M        6 
VM_ALLOCATE                         40K        4 
__DATA                            20.8M      208 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        2 
__LINKEDIT                       187.0M        4 
__TEXT                           130.2M      214 
__UNICODE                          556K        2 
mapped file                       41.5M        9 
shared memory                      756K       10 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            545.8M      504 

Model: MacBookPro14,3, BootROM MBP143.0167.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.45f0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 630, Intel HD Graphics 630, Built-In
Graphics: Radeon Pro 560, Radeon Pro 560, PCIe, 4 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x173), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.0.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.0f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: iBridge
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.3
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.3
```

Full paste on https://pastebin.com/raw/CPTJa76H. I had to remove some of the lines under Binary Images.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - did you end up resolving this?

Comment: No! I decided not to install the drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Turns out I could get it connected to wifi and macOS was able to find it as a printer and install whatever it needed to there.

Answer (score 1):

This sloppy installation application also crash in my Mac 10.13 for the Brother HL-L2340DW printer. I solved it pressing WPS/AOSS in the router and the the WiFi button in the printer. Then the printer will appear in System Preferences|Printers|+ as a Bounjour device.